# Hiding/Unhiding SharePoint list/doc library columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010, listitem, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have added some javascript in a content editor to the EditForm.aspx page of a document library. I have the following columns in my document library:

- Title
- Description

The javascript hides the "Description" field when when a new item is added, this works great however I then want to the be able to unhide/show the "Description" field if the "Title" has/contains any of the following values when adding a new item:

-TestItem1
-TestItem2
-TestItem3

I feel like I am half way there but just not sure how to achieve the unhiding/showing part, the javascript I have so far is listed below:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

<!--

//Custom functionality to hide selected columns from the form

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideFields");

function findAControl(fieldName){

    var arr=document.getElementsByTagName("!");

    //get all comments
    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        //now match the field name
        if(arr[i].innerHTML.indexOf(fieldName) > 0)
        {
            return arr[i];

        }
    }
}

function hideFields(){


    var control = findControl("Description");
    control.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";
}

//end custom functionality-->
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
var control = findAControl("Description");
```